# How to find dependency path in Android From Source to Sink?

Tags: android, reflection, soot

I wanted to find Full Dependency path in android from source to sink, for example there is a function in Class Test at Line no 10, i wanted to find the lines affected by or who is calling line no 10.

Comment: Try `ALT + F7` .

Answer (score 0):

Did you take a look at the Soot Framework ? It allows you to statically build a complete call graph of your application, given its APK.
From this call graph, you should be able to retrieve dependency path using def-use analysis.

If you are looking for an in-depth information flow analysis, FlowDroid does that.
FlowDroid is a static analysis tool built on Soot which allows you to retrieve data flow between sources and sinks.

Hope it will help
Best

Comment: Thank, can you please help me out with the soot framework, i have used it but i have very little knowledge about it

Comment: It is hard to help you out without knowing exactly what you want to do. My advice is to start by taking a look at the soot tutorials on the soot wiki here : 
[https://github.com/Sable/soot/wiki](https://github.com/Sable/soot/wiki)

Later, you should take a look at multiple soot projects that instrument Android apk such as Flowdroid or DroidForce.